# How to retrieve Spring context loaded in Tomcat from outside application

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to do the following:

Imagine you have a Java EE application running on Tomcat using Spring as the IoC engine.

I have another jar in the application that has full access to all the resources. i.e. I can instantiate the same application context that is running in tomcat but it takes around 30 seconds to instantiate all the dependencies.

Anyone knows if it is feasible to retrieve current tomcats ApplicationContext from the outside?

There is a way to ask for the WebApplicationContext inside a servlet but I'm not on it, I only have a jar with a main method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You have to be running within tomcat (a webapp) to be able to access the servlet context (and from there - the application context). You are not even in the same runtime with the main method.

If you want to get some information from the context, you should expose it as a service. For example:

- a restful service, via Spring-MVC
- via JMX
- via JNDI